# Put to sleep unless there is something downloading/uploading

Tags: windows, windows-8

I wanted to know if it's possible to set the PC to go to sleep after X amount of time, unless there is some data going through the ethernet or wifi, like a torrent or my media server.

Comment: This sounds like a good idea in theory, but I think it could lead to unpredictable behavior and turn out to be a source of frustration. There are so many potential problems... for example: you pause a movie for a while to take a phone call- no Ethernet activity, so server goes to sleep. Try to play movie again but get error message "resource unavailable". Or how about a torrent can't find any seeders for a few minutes for a rare download- no network activity for a while, so ends up shutting down prematurely (before download is complete). Conversely it might not sleep when it IS supposed to!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A program like [Shutter](http://www.den4b.com/?x=products&product=shutter) might be able to help:

> Shutter is a multifunctional scheduling utility, which has a user friendly and easy-to-use interface and supports many different Events and Actions. Events: Countdown, On Time, Winamp Stops, Low CPU Usage, User Inactive, Battery Low, Window Closes, Process Stops, Ping Stops, File Size Limit. Actions: Shutdown, Reboot, Log Off, Lock Workstation, Sleep, Hibernate, Monitor Turn Off, Un/Mute Master Volume, Hang Up, Alarm, Play Sound, Execute Program.
>
> Desktop links can be created to execute any of the supported actions directly from desktop. Web Interface allows remote execution of actions and displays run-time information about the computer: Up Time, List of Processes, Screenshot of a Desktop, Program Execution, and more.

[image: 1]